Examples of bans 2sxc
On the 2sxc portal, I found the Swiper app that I can use to include on my website, however I would like more varieties of banners. for me to install and apply on my website. Where can I find more examples with other layouts?
enter image description here
I tried to research more varieties of banner apps to include on my website

I am not understanding your question very well. Can you explain better what you have so far and maybe show an example of what result you want instead? Also, in your title above, what does "bans" mean? Did you misspell "banners" or did you use a translator and bans is a word I don't know in another language?

I also don't understand the question. I think it's best you just install the app and try a few things.
